# How to recognize if a cookie is set by javascript or not (client-side)

Tags: javascript, python, selenium, web-scraping

I am working with selenium and python. I need to know if a particular cookie is set by javascript or not. Is there a way to do that?

Answer (score 0):

I use https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie works perfect.

Read cookie:

```
$.cookie('the_cookie'); // => "the_value"
$.cookie('not_existing'); // => undefined
```